# When do you detect the presence of evil when using Detect Evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, concentration

[Detect Evil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-evil/)

[Concentration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Duration)

Its my understanding that you only get the benefits (1st rnd detect presence, 2nd rnd # of auras, etc) of Detect Evil when you concentrate on the spell, not just cast it. Since casting a spell and concentrating on a spell both require standard actions, if you cast Detect Evil in round 1 you wont detect the presence of evil until round 2 when you concentrate on it. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 5):

### As soon as you cast the spell

*Concentration* doesn't happen only when you are injured or when you have to spend a *Standard Action* to concentrate on a spell. Rather, any spell being cast requires concentration, and the duration of this concentration depends on the spell being cast, it may last for a *Standard Action*, a full round, or multiple rounds, for spells that require concentration like [Detect Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic/)/[Evil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-evil/).

From the Magic rules on [Concentration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Concentration):

> **Concentration Checks and Casting Spells**
>
> To cast a spell, you must concentrate. If something interrupts your concentration while you’re casting, you must make a concentration check or lose the spell.

Otherwise, spells with *"concentration"* duration would fail automatically because you did not concentrate (the *Standard Action*) on the round you cast the spell.

So, for example, if you cast *Detect Evil*, on the very first round that you cast the spell, you can tell if there is something evil within the 60 ft cone of the spell's effect. Then you can keep concentrating to try to obtain more info, or move the cone to attempt to search another area.

Contrary to the spell's description, which says that *"the amount of information revealed depends on how long you study a particular area or subject."*, you don't actually need to make [Perception](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception/) checks to notice those auras (the spell handles that). "Studying" here is talking about concentrating on the spell while looking at objects and creatures within the area of the spell.

If you decided to *also* attempt to notice something not obvious using a *Move Action* (described as "Intentionally searching for stimulus"), then you could make *Perception* checks to notice something else other than the auras you are looking for.

For instance, you could be trying to notice both magic auras within a 60 ft cone in front of you, and try to pinpoint the location of a sound around you by making a *Perception* check. Since you get to pick the order of your actions, you could attempt to find the location of a sound (say, an invisible enemy casting spells) and then move your detect-cone to that direction to see if there are any magic auras there.

To simplify: **You detect the presence of auras/evil on the round that the spell is cast**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: Two questions though. 1st, does the concentration on the casting of the spell count as the concentration ON the spell for detecting evil? and 2nd, the first round says: "1st Round: Presence or absence of evil." So it doesnt show just evil auras on the first round,  but the presence of evil altogether. So a 1HD evil aligned humanoid would register even though he doesnt have an aura right?

Comment: The description of the spell clarifies that. Unless they have a strong aligned aura, like a cleric of an evil god, they are not automatically detected as evil. Only if their HD is a little higher.

Comment: Can you clarify that in your answer? Also what about part 1 of my comment?

Comment: @Semada to be honest, that is on the description of the spell, and not part of the question. As for the first question on your comment, that is on my answer already: *" You detect the presence of auras on the round that the spell is cast."* Or did I understand it incorrectly?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Just because something is evil, doesnt mean it has an aura. The spell says you detect the presence of evil on the first round, not evil auras.

Comment: We are using "aura" for different things here. By aura I meant whatever magical visual clue you get from the spell. Not the aura granted by followers of an evil god. Keep in mind that "aura" is not a defined game term.

Comment: I was answering in a more generic way because those visual clues are generally called "auras" in spells. From *Detect Magic*: *"Round 1: Presence or absence of magical auras."*. Even *Detect Evil* calls those visual clues as auras, from the table: *"Aura Power"*

Comment: I disagree. All magic gives off an aura according to Detect Magic, but not all evil creatures give off auras. The table in Detect Evil says so. A 1HD evil aligned humanoid that doesn't follow a god still has NO aura to be seen.

Comment: I well aware of that. Im not sure where you are getting the impression that im saying the opposite.

Comment: What I told is that the answer doesnt need to explain how the spell works, that wasnt in the question. The spell does a good job at explaining that 1-4 HD evil creatures *will not* be detected, so why I have to say that again? Is the spell text unclear?

Comment: Your answer is unclear. You say "As soon as you cast the spell" and "You detect the presence of auras/evil on the round that the spell is cast" but Detect Evil says you only detect the presence of EVIL not EVIL AURAS in the 1st round. 2nd and 3rd show the auras. So contradictory to your last comment, 1-4HD evil creatures WILL be detected in the 1st round.

Comment: Semada, you are being picky on the words for no reason. Its clear that the spell works like detect magic. I wont beat around semantics when everybody uses the spell the correct way.

Comment: Comments are to improve an answer, not answer new questions. Open another question if you are in doubt about creatures with 1-4 HD being detected.